# OpenLaszlo DHTML migration from 4.9 to 5.0 issue

Tags: dhtml, openlaszlo, lzx

I am trying to migrate my 4.9 DHTML application to 5.0. When i am doing that i am getting an error

```
ReferenceError: EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

this.sendAAEvent(0,EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS)
```

And in the line i am seeing this set of code. From the class name it looks like it is a radiobutton class.

```
    $lzc$class_baselistitem,["tagname","radiobutton","children",[{attrs:{$CSSDescriptor:{},$attributeDescriptor:{types:LzNode.mergeAttributeTypes(lz.ClassAttributeTypes["accessible"],{EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS:"number",EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE:"number",EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTION:"number",EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE:"number"})},$classrootdepth:1,$delegates:["onselected","$mb5",null,"ontext","$mb6",null],$mb5:function($0){
if(!this.isinited){
return
};if(this.selected){
this.sendAAEvent(0,EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS)
};this.sendAAEvent(0,EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE,true)
},$mb6:function($0){
this.sendAAEvent(0,EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE)
},EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS:32773,EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE:32780,EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTION:32774,EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE:32778,name:"accessible",updateFocus:function($0){
if($0){
this.sendAAEvent(0,EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTION);this.sendAAEvent(0,EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS)
};this.sendAAEvent(0,EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE,true)
}},"class":LzState}
```

This is happening because of the radio.lzx .has anyone come across an issue like this.

I am currently using FF 16.0 windows xp sp 3 and Openlaszlo 5.0.x revision 19830

Comment: Any example code which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @RajuBitter: I am trying to generate a scenario like this

Comment: In the Firebug debugger, can you identify the line of generated JavaScript code which is causing the problem? For which LZX file is the exception reported? And tell us the exact version of OpenLaszlo you are using (the value of the `canvas.lpsbuild` attribute).

Comment: The code which is causing the problem deals with accessibility. I've never seen that error. Try to create a small LZX test case and file a bug in the OpenLaszlo JIRA.

Comment: @RajuBitter: Ok..I'll try to replicate the scenario

Answer (score 1):

I would try with a different Firefox version or Firefox on a different OS. I have the feeling that it might be a Firefox bug in one specific version of Firefox.

The only mention of the `EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS` can be found in OpenLaszlo's JIRA issue [LPP-7594 Jaws Accessibility support needed for Radioboxes](http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-7594). It doesn't seem that any bug has been filed.